# Unable to start node on Weblogic dynamic cluster

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing, weblogic12c

I am trying to set up WLS dynamic cluster on two machines.

Two nodes are up and running on one of machine where admin server is hosted as well, but when I try to start the node which is on different machine that I have added afterwards I see below exception.

```
<Jun 7, 2016 2:13:07 AM PDT> <Critical> <Security> <BEA-090518> <Could not decrypt the username attribute value of {AES}Q64tW2ys+PviYQPkPGPc8/c79/RwfgrsoekwDFpgZKI= from the file /usr/home/devtools/Middleware/user_projects/domains/v12C_d/servers/Cluster-0-abc-4/data/nodemanager/boot.properties. If an encrypted attribute was copied from boot.properties from another domain into /usr/home/devtools/Middleware/user_projects/domains/v12C_d/servers/Cluster-0-abc-4/data/nodemanager/boot.properties, change the encrypted attribute to its clear text value, and then restart the server. The attribute will be encrypted again. Otherwise, change all encrypted attributes to their clear text values, then restart the server. All encryptable attributes will be encrypted again. The decryption failed with the exception weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding..>   
<Jun 7, 2016 2:13:07 AM PDT> <Critical> <Security> <BEA-090518> <Could not decrypt the password attribute value of {AES}qusooByFxC/eTogSMU2YEjfnWRpY69f6MfTeqhqfIFk= from the file /usr/home/devtools/Middleware/user_projects/domains/v12C_d/servers/Cluster-0-abc-4/data/nodemanager/boot.properties. If an encrypted attribute was copied from boot.properties from another domain into /usr/home/devtools/Middleware/user_projects/domains/v12C_d/servers/Cluster-0-abc-4/data/nodemanager/boot.properties, change the encrypted attribute to its clear text value, and then restart the server. The attribute will be encrypted again. Otherwise, change all encrypted attributes to their clear text values, then restart the server. All encryptable attributes will be encrypted again. The decryption failed with the exception weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding..>   
Enter username to boot WebLogic server:<Jun 7, 2016 2:13:09 AM PDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141307> <Unable to connect to the Administration Server. Waiting 5 second(s) to retry (attempt number 1 of 3).>   
<Jun 7, 2016 2:13:14 AM PDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141307> <Unable to connect to the Administration Server. Waiting 5 second(s) to retry (attempt number 2 of 3).>
```

On doing a search on internet I saw solutions such as giving the clear userid/password of weblogic admin in boot.properties file and upon restart the userid/password would get encrypted and issue should be fixed.

Well I have tried that and that didn't fix my issue.

Please note that I am using dynamic cluster which suggests that configurations are usually copied over nodes based on server templates.

Will really appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

1) Scale down your cluster to a single instance where the boot.properties files is known to work.

2) Change it to clear text.

3) Bounce WebLogic so it get's the file encrypted once again.

4) Make sure it works.

5) Scale Up your cluster again and see if the error persist.